# dynamic_cast<D *>(pb) return null

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

In C++ primer(5th) 19.2.1 about dynamic_cast. It says, for `dynamic_cast<type*>(e)` to be successful,

> the type of e must be either a class type that is publicly derived from
>   the target type, **a public base class of the target type**, or the same as the target
>   type

However, for the following code:

```
class B{
  public:
    virtual ~B(){}
};

class D : public B{};

B *pb = new B;
D *pd = dynamic_cast<D*>(pb);
if(pd == 0) cout << "err" << endl;
```

The output is "err". But the type of pb is a public base class of type D.

Is this a mistake in C++ primer(5th)? Or do I just misunderstand these words?

Comment: `pb` has to point to a `D` to begin with. You have a `B`.

Comment: You misunderstood the words.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Since `pb` has type `B*`, it cannot point at anything other than a `B`.

Comment: @KerrekSB - `D` is-a `B` however :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `pb` is indeed a public base class of `D`, but the object that `pb` points to is *not* the base subobject of any object of type `D`. The dynamic cast detects this and returns null.

If indeed you did attempt to cast the pointer to a base subobject of a `D` object, you would get the (non-null) pointer to the `D` object:

```
D obj;
B *pb = &obj;   // points at subobject

assert(&obj == dynamic_cast<D*>(pb));
```

The requirement that you've cited is merely a static requirement that allows you to use the dynamic cast at all -- but it does not describe the *result* of using the cast. That's described later on.

Comment: Got your idea, the requirement is a little bit misleading.Thanks

Comment: @YuanWen: Not really. The requirement says that you cannot write something like `dynamic_cast<double>(4)`, say.

Answer (score 2):

`dynamic_cast` can be used as a tool to detect if an object is derived from another one or not, in the code you've written, the answer is NO, so you got a null. By

```
B *pb = new B;
D *pd = dynamic_cast<D*>(pb);
```

You're down-casting a base to a derived, and it is reverse of what the documet is saying. Of course you can have below if `pb` points to an extact `D*`:

```
B *pb = new D; // <--- It is a `D`
D *pd = dynamic_cast<D*>(pb);
```